# How to order bootstrap panels in a grid when a new value is added?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a grid based on bootstrap 3 with col / rows
inside each col there is a panel with a value,
the values are got from DB yet ordered but the user could add a new panel manually and i would be able to set it ordered correctly..

like my grid could contain

1 2 3 +

when + is clicked the user could add 4 that should be added after 3 or he could add 1.50 which should be added before 2 and so on

Here is how my grid looks like with an example of static add

```js
$('.add').on("click", function() { // in live version i'm adding new col after AJAX request response is gone OK
  $('<div>', {
    class: 'col-md-3'
  }).append(
    $('<div>', {
      class: 'panel panel-default taglio'
    }).append(
      $('<div>', {
        class: 'panel-body text-center'
      }).text("€" + parseFloat(1.50).toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."))
    ).data('id', -1)
  ).insertBefore($(this).parent());
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default taglio">
      <div class="panel-body text-center">€10.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default taglio">
      <div class="panel-body text-center">€15.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default taglio">
      <div class="panel-body text-center">€5.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default taglio">
      <div class="panel-body text-center">€10.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAdd">
      <div class="panel-body text-center">+</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So how could i reorder the panels each time a new item is added?

Comment: You can achieve this by creating array on frontend and then update the array on every new record.

Comment: Hi, you need to rearrange the divs positions?

Comment: @Swati exactly, when a new item is added it's position have to be set in the correct order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As, you are displaying prices inside your div you can use `.find` and `.replace` to get exact price from divs and compare them inside `sort` function then append sorted divs inside your main div again.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).on("click", ".add", function() {
  $('<div>', {
    class: 'col-md-3'
  }).append(
    $('<div>', {
      class: 'panel panel-default taglio'
    }).append(
      $('<div>', {
        class: 'panel-body text-center'
      }).text("€" + parseFloat(7.50).toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."))
    ).data('id', -1)
  ).insertBefore($(this).parent());
  //sort your divs
  var result = $('div.mian_div > div').sort(function(a, b) {
    //get price 
    var contentA = parseFloat($(a).find('.taglio > div').text().replace('€', '').trim());
    var contentB = parseFloat($(b).find('.taglio > div').text().replace('€', '').trim());
    return (contentA < contentB) ? -1 : (contentA > contentB) ? 1 : 0;
  });
  $('div.mian_div').html($(result)) //add result
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row mian_div">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default taglio">
      <div class="panel-body text-center">€10.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default taglio">
      <div class="panel-body text-center">€15.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default taglio">
      <div class="panel-body text-center">€5.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default taglio">
      <div class="panel-body text-center">€10.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAdd">
      <div class="panel-body text-center">+</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```